# Drawing on UIImageView in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, drawing, core-graphics, drawrect

I am trying to develop an app where I can draw something on the UIImageView. I have got the following code.

```
import UIKit
class Line
{
    var startPoint:CGPoint
    var endPoint:CGPoint

    init (start:CGPoint , end:CGPoint)
    {
        startPoint = start
        endPoint = end
    }
}


class AnnotationView: UIView {

    static internal let nibName = "AnnotationView"
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var lines :[Line] = []
    var lastPoint:CGPoint!


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        lastPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch  = touches.first
        {
            let newPoint = touch.location(in:self)
            lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint))
            lastPoint = newPoint
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        {
            context.beginPath()
            for line in lines
            {
                context.move(to: line.startPoint)
                context.addLine(to: line.endPoint)
            }
            context.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
            context.setStrokeColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            context.setLineWidth(5)
            context.strokePath()
        }
    }
}
```

so now in the above code I have AnnotationView class derived from UIView where I have a UIImageView which I set to full size of the superview from the interface builder. This is a simple drawing app where I want to draw somethings on the UIImageView. Now the problem is when the imageView.image is nil then it does show my drawing and if there is any image set for imageView.image then it doesn't show the drawing. It just show the image that is set in this imageView. I have debugged in both scenarios all the methods get called. There is surely something which I am missing. Can anyone please help me? I want to show my drawing on top of the image which I have set in my UIImageView.
Regards,
neena

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're drawing in the `AnnotationView`'s main layer which is laid behind any of its subviews, including your `UIImageView`. The solution is to move your drawing to separate `sublayer` added to `AnnotationView`'s main layer.

Instead of drawing your lines directly in `draw()` method, you need to have a separate layer for your drawing overlay. Add this property to your `AnnotationView`:

```
let drawingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
```

And override `awakeFromNib()` to make this layer a sublayer on top of everything else as soon as your view is loaded from Storyboard/Nib:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    layer.addSublayer(drawingLayer)
}
```

Now let's create a function to call every time you need to update your overlay instead of calling `setNeedsDisplay()`:

```
func updateDrawingOverlay() {
    let path = CGMutablePath()

    for line in lines {
        path.move(to: line.startPoint)
        path.addLine(to: line.endPoint)
    }

    drawingLayer.frame = imageView.frame
    drawingLayer.path = path
    drawingLayer.lineWidth = 5
    drawingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Delete your code in `draw(_:)` method since it's redundant now, and replace  `setNeedsDisplay()` call from `touchesMoved(_: with:)` with `updateDrawingOverlay()` call.

---

The whole thing should look like this for you:

```
import UIKit

class Line {
    var startPoint:CGPoint
    var endPoint:CGPoint

    init (start:CGPoint , end:CGPoint) {
        startPoint = start
        endPoint = end
    }
}


class AnnotationView: UIView {
    static internal let nibName = "AnnotationView"
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var lines :[Line] = []
    var lastPoint:CGPoint!
    let drawingLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        layer.addSublayer(drawingLayer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        lastPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch  = touches.first
        {
            let newPoint = touch.location(in:self)
            lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint))
            lastPoint = newPoint
            updateDrawingOverlay()
        }
    }

    func updateDrawingOverlay() {
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        for line in lines {
            path.move(to: line.startPoint)
            path.addLine(to: line.endPoint)
        }

        drawingLayer.frame = imageView.frame
        drawingLayer.path = path
        drawingLayer.lineWidth = 5
        drawingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

This should do the trick, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but its not drawing anything with/without the image ...

Comment: @neena Please try to copy-paste new version, I replaced `init(frame:)` with `awakeFromNib()`, to make sure your image view is loaded before adding overlay. Let me know if worked or not.